# Django. Не сохраняется запись в БД через связь OneToOneField

Tags: python-3.x, django

Есть модель связанная с моделью User:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    website= models.URLField(blank=True)
```

Есть вьюха для получения нужного поля website:

```
def register_profile(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        user = User.objects.get(id = request.user.id)

        if form.is_valid():
            user_profile = UserProfile(user = user)
            website = request.POST['website']
            user_profile.website = website
            user_profile.save()
            return redirect('/index/')
```

Но после этого, поле в БД всё равно остаетя пустым. Почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В чем была проблема не понял, но замена OneToOneField на ForeignKey помогло.